# Expectation of an exponent of a random variable

Tags: exponential-function, expectation

Suppose that $X \geq 0$ is distributed according to some distribution $F$. What can be said about $E[e^{-r X}]$? 
I.e. is there a way to express this expectation only in terms of some characteristics of the distribution $F$ (mean, variance, etc)?

It is a part of a project where I try to find a distribution $F$, but I am stuck at this step.

Comment: The function $r \mapsto \mathbb{E}[e^{rx}]$ is the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function), and under certain conditions, taking the $n$th derivative and evaluating at zero gives you the $n$th moment $\mathbb{E}[X^n]$; in particular you can obtain the mean and variance from it. You seem to be asking for the converse though.

Comment: Where you wrote $E[e^{-rx}]$, did you actually mean $E[e^{-rX}]$? $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, you are both right, of course.